# Ways to write "50"

Tags: soft-question, big-list

A really good friend of mine is an elementary school math teacher.  He is turning 50, and we want to put a mathematical expression that equals 50 on his birthday cake but goes beyond the typical "order of operations" problems.  Some simple examples are 
$$e^{\ln{50}}$$
$$100\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}$$
$$25\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}$$
$$\frac{300}{\pi^2}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

What are some other creative ways I can top his cake?

I should note that he is an elementary school teacher.  Now he LOVES math, and I can certainly show him a lot of expressions.  I don't want them so difficult that it takes a masters degree to solve, but they should certainly be interesting enough to cause him to be wowed.  Elementary functions are good, summations are also good, integrals can be explained, so this is the type of expression I'm looking for...

EDIT:: I would make a note that we are talking about a cake here, so use your judgement from here on out.  Think of a normal rectangular cake and how big it is. Hence, long strings of numbers, complex integrals, and long summations are not going to work.  I appreciate the answers but I need more compact expressions.

Comment: See this question for a different take on $50$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225518/properties-of-the-number-50

Comment: There's surely a contour integral/residue type expression.

Comment: $e^{2\pi i}+7^2,$ $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-10}^{10}\sqrt{100-x^2}dx.$

Comment: $25\nabla\cdot\nabla|x|^2$

Comment: "Raleigh quotient" expression for matrix with maximum eigenvalue of 50

Comment: Do you know what his favourite expression/identity/theorem is? Maybe you find something using that. (If somebody were to do that for me, I'd like to see $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ integrated.)

Comment: @MarkBennet that is a great link.  I might just type him up a booklet with all those fun facts too.

Comment: He likes the summation formulas because he understands them.  I could certainly explain integrals to him too.

Comment: What a wonderful idea. This is certainly something I'd love to get for my birthday. :) For my mother's 75th I had cake decorated with an epicycloid with 75 cusps. Not that she's into math, but she sees the beauty in geometrical shapes.

Comment: See also this list [here](http://calculus-geometry.hubpages.com/hub/Fun-Facts-and-Mathematical-Properties-of-the-Number-50)

Comment: I voted to reopen. Perhaps this should be Community Wiki. It is tagged as big list - to say that there are lots of possible answers rather validates the list - the number of interesting answers is probably rather smaller, and voting will distinguish the cases. Given that there was a debate about my question on the number 50, I think there should be a proper debate about this one. Maybe there should be a "birthday fun facts" tag related to recreational mathematics. Such fun facts can have serious content, and some of us enjoy them.

Comment: How about $100\sin(\pi/6)$ for the second one? [sine is negative on the interval $(\pi, 2\pi)$.]

Comment: I would totally troll your math teacher and write $$7^2$$ while saying "happy 50th birthday"

Comment: @MarkBennet I made the question CW and protected to repel trolls.  However, I do think the question should be closed for broadness, though I do not feel strongly enough to act unilaterally.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: I certainly see the case to be made for broadness - there are many possible good answers and some might say too many. However from a more pragmatic viewpoint, I believe this is a good question and I don't see a way to ask it where it isn't too broad.

Comment: @RghtHndSd That still means it's too broad, though.  (I would also argue that it is too localized, if that were still a thing.)  There are lots of good questions which do not fit the format of this site.  But, again, the decision is up the the community.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Thanks - I appreciate that. I do see your point, but think a little fun every so often isn't out of place, and several of the answers are well in the spirit of the question.

Comment: $50$ $\text{ }$

Comment: Is there any special significance to the number *50* that I'm not aware of? Also - I can offer *L*, the from the Roman numbering system.

Comment: $\lfloor e^4-e^{1.5}\rfloor$

Comment: $\lfloor\exp(H_28)\rfloor$

Comment: I would like to just mention that since the idea was about a cake topper or something for a birthday cake that perhaps I should limit the "size" of the expression.  Something compact like summations or products are useful because they can fit on a rectangular cake.  Hopefully that helps narrow the field from here on in. Also, stuff like Roman Numerals are really not the place here, easy fractions like 100/2 are not really what I was after.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer, I edited the question.

Comment: Could someone explain to me how this is different from any other community wiki? If your response is that "49+1,48+2,47+3..." are all possible answers, then I say that those are all very bad answers, and to any community wiki one can always find many many very bad answers.

Comment: I am surprised not to see $3^2+4^2+5^2$

Answer (score 49, accepted):

We can use only two [famous numbers in mathematics](http://list25.com/25-famous-numbers-and-why-they-are-important/), [$\large\pi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) and [$\large e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29), to produce number $50$.

[$$\bbox[8pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\Large \lfloor e^\pi \rfloor + \lfloor \pi^e \rfloor + \lfloor \pi \rfloor + \lfloor e \rfloor = 50}}
$$](http://wolfr.am/24dbxKEa)

<sup>Click the box to see Wolfram Alpha's output to confirm the result</sup>

Answer (score 56):

$$\frac{2^{\frac{(2\cdot2)!}{2+2}}+22+2^{2^2}-\sqrt 2^2}{2^{2-\frac{2}{2}}}$$

Comment: That is an awesome one.

Comment: I think it is 2 much.

Comment: @RghtHndSd 2 good 2 be 2rue?

Comment: This answer currently has 22 upvotes. Don't ever let that change.

Comment: @teadawg1337 Don't worry. As of right now, the counter's at $22 + \lim_{n\to \infty}(\varphi(2)+\dfrac {2\pi i}{n})^n$.

Comment: @teadawg1337 Damn, it changed. But I just upvoted it to $2^{2^2+2^{2-2}}$ so I think it's OK again.

Comment: People, it is over 22 upvotes now. Let's make it 222.

Comment: @RghtHndSd 42nd upvote. Let's get it to 50.

Comment: Upvoted to $\displaystyle\left\lfloor 2\sum _{s=2}^{222}\frac{s}{2222}\cdot 2\right\rfloor-2$

Comment: For non math geeks, can someone explain this? How the result is 50 here?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra First, we take $2^{\frac{(2\cdot 2!)}{2+2}}$, which is $2^{\frac{24}{4}}$, finally resulting in $64$ (because $\frac{24}{4}=6$, and $2^6=64$). $64+22+2^{2^2}$ (which is $16$) is $102$, $102-\sqrt{2}^2$ (which is $2$) becomes $100$. $2^{2-\frac{2}{2}}$ becomes $2^{2-1}$, which is $2^1$, which is $2$, which is $\frac{100}{2}$, resulting in $50$.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien [but how (2.2!) = 24?](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=(2.2!))

Comment: It's not $2.2!$, its $2\cdot 2!$, or, alternatively, $2\times 2!$

Comment: Oh. now everything clear. Thanks @ConorO'Brien

Comment: @Krishnabhadra My pleasure, and Merry Christmas!

Comment: 50! there you go.

Answer (score 36):

$$50 = 2\cdot(2\varphi - 1)^4$$
where $\varphi$ is the [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

---

$$50 = \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} (0.98)^i$$

(Geometric series)

---

$$50  = \left(\left(\frac{5^5-5}{5}+5^0\right)\cdot\left(5-5^0\right)\right)^{0.5}$$

$$50 = 0.5 \cdot (5+5)^{\frac{5^0}{0.5}}$$

$$50 = 5\cdot\left(\frac{5}{0.5}+5^0\right)-5$$

(Using only the digits "5" and "0")

---

$$50 = \frac{3^{3!}-3^{3-3^0}}{3^{3-3^0}}-30$$

(Using only the digits "3" and "0")

---

$$50 = \frac{(10i)^2\log(i^i)}{\pi}$$

(Using imaginary unit $i$)

---

$$50 = 3 + 47$$
$$50 = 7 + 43$$
$$50 = 13 + 37$$
$$50 = 19 + 31$$

(As sum of two prime numbers)

---

$$50 = (7+11)\frac{11}{11-7}+\frac{7+11}{11-7}-11+7$$

(Using only the two next prime numbers of $5$)

---

$$ 50 = 7+3+ (7-3)\cdot(7+3)$$

(Using only the previous and next prime numbers of $5$)

---

$$50 = 3\cdot(2^3+3^2)-(2\cdot 3)^{3-2}+3+2$$

(Using only the two previous prime numbers of $5$)

---

$$ 50 = (1^6-2^5+3^4-4^3+5^2-6^1)^2\cdot(4^1 - 3^2 + 2^3 - 1^4)$$
$$ 50 = 3 - (1^9-2^8+3^7-4^6+5^5-6^4+7^3-8^2+9^1)$$
(Using bases/powers in reverse order)

Comment: I love the bases/powers in reverse order and i think he will get a kick out of that.

Comment: I particularly like the ones using only the digits 5 and 0.

Answer (score 35):

No fancy math here, but if you want to emphasize how old your friend is getting, nothing says it better than implying he's halfway to the century mark:

$$100\over2$$

Comment: Or 25 x 2, if you want to say: "hey, your body is just like 25 and your mind is better than that, twice."

Comment: @Ooker Or vice versa :-)

Comment: @Ooker & Venus, When I turned 50, my (older) brother sent me a birthday email with instructions to "party like you're a pair of 25-year-olds."  Or maybe it was to party *with* a pair of 25-year-olds....

Answer (score 25):

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50_(number))

> Fifty is the smallest number that is the sum of two non-zero square
>   numbers in two distinct ways: $50 = 1^2 + 7^2 = 5^2 + 5^2$.

So you could write something like
\begin{align}
50 = \min_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\{n =p_i^2+p_j^2=p_k^2+p_l^2 \quad | \quad p_i,p_j,p_k,p_l\in\mathbb{N} \quad \wedge\quad p_k \not =p_i \not = p_l \}
\end{align}

I like it, because it doesn't involve some sort of scaling and is not obvious (at least not for me).

Comment: He's going to need a **long** cake for this!!

Comment: I have a proof of this theorem, but there is not enough space on this cake.

Comment: Why not just write $1^2 + 7^2 = 5^2 + 5^2$. When people ask "what the heck?" you can give them a math lesson.

Answer (score 15):

We also have
\begin{align*}
50 &= 11+12+13+14 \\ 
&= (8+4)+(8-4)+(8\cdot 4)+(8/4) \\ 
&= 4^2 + 4^2 + 3^2 + 3^2\\
&= 6^2 + 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2\\
&= (7+i)(7-i) \\
&= (10-\color{red}{5})(10-\color{red}{0})\\
&= 10(\color{red}{5}+\color{red}{0})\\
&= \sqrt{30^2+40^2}\\
&= \sqrt[3]{170^2+310^2}\\
&= \sqrt[3]{146^2+322^2}\\
&= \sqrt[3]{50^2+350^2}\\
\end{align*}
Finally $50= 2 + 4 + 8 + 12 + 24$ and $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{24} = 1$.

Comment: This is a great great list.

Answer (score 12):

I hope he doesn't calculate it by adding all numbers ;)

\begin{align}
50 = \sum_{k=0}^{100} (-1)^k k
\end{align}

And a last one, involving only $4$s and $9$s:

\begin{align}
4^9 \mod 49 + \sqrt{49}
\end{align}

Answer (score 10):

Whenever one of my friends has a birthday, I find out how old they get and then I visit [their number on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50_%28number%29)

For your friend, I would write something like this:

> 50 is the smallest number that is the sum of two non-zero square numbers in two distinct ways: $1^2 + 7^2$ and $5^2 + 5^2$. It is also the sum of three squares, $3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2$. It is also a Harshad number and a nontotient and a noncototient. 50 is the aliquot sum of 40 and 94. 50 is also the atomic number of tin and fifth magic number in nuclear physics.

While many of the things on Wikipedia are not Mathematical expressions, and some of it is way too long to write on a cake, I am certain that this will brighten his day if you tell him this stuff!

As for a mathematical expression, I'd go with either $3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2$ because I find it simple but elegant, or fill the cake with stuff like "Harshad number, 5th magic number in nuclear physics, nontotient", etc. and see if he can figure out how old he is.

Answer (score 8):

binary code : 50 is given by 110010

Answer (score 8):

$\displaystyle \left(4!-5!-4\right)\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{-1}(t) }{t}\mathbb{d}t$
Although this next one may be too big to fit on a cake, it's certainly beautiful:
$\displaystyle \frac{\pi\operatorname{Li}_1(\frac12)(\Gamma(5)+1)}{\left[\Gamma(\frac32)\right]^2\left(\frac{\Gamma'(1)}{\Gamma(1)}-\frac{\Gamma'({\frac12})}{\Gamma({\frac12})}\right)}$
Here's another one that may or may not fit on a cake:
$\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\left(1+2\sqrt{4!+5!}\right)\left[\prod_{n=1}^3\Gamma\left(\frac{n}3\right)\right]^2}{\displaystyle{e}^{2\operatorname{Li}_1(\frac12)}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{\Gamma'(1)}{\Psi(1)}\right)}$

Comment: Ironically, when I am reading this it says "answered 50 seconds ago"

Comment: To whoever just downvoted, $\displaystyle \left(\operatorname{Li}_n(1) =\zeta(n)\right) \land \left(\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\right)\Rightarrow\left(\operatorname{Li}_0(1) =-\frac{1}{2}\right)$. See Equation 86 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) for proof that $\displaystyle \zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Someone is downvoting everything in here. Don't take it personally.

Comment: what's $Li$? I've never seen that notation.

Comment: @OriaGruber $\operatorname{Li}$ is the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html)

Comment: This looks like stuff Ramanujan would have written.

Comment: @MackTuesday I'm flattered, but the last two expressions have terms that simplify and cancel out to result in the number 50. Nothing special, just really fancy notation :)

Answer (score 7):

I went to visit him while he was lying ill at the hospital.I had come in taxi cab number $50$ and remarked that it was a rather dull number. "No" he replied, "it is a very interesting number. It's the smallest number expressible as the product of $25$ and $2$  in two different ways." 
https://mathoverflow.net/a/2197/15296

Comment: Hilariously, 50 is the smallest number expressible as the sum of two squares in two different ways, as noted in another answer, which is where I thought you were going with this at first!

Answer (score 6):

$$
\begin{align}
&50 = \frac{5}{24} \zeta(-7)\\
&50 = \frac{ 1600 \sqrt{2} }{3 \pi ^3}\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^2 \log ^2(x)}{x^4+1} \, dx
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Well, OK, but then you can take any real-valued expression, multiply it by the appropriate number so that it gives 50... I mean it _does_ answer the question but it is not as elegant as an expression which would be specific to 50. (this comment also applies to other answers)

Answer (score 5):

$$-\frac{12!! - 3^{10}}{705 \text{ mod } 101}-\int_0^3 4x^3\;dx = 50$$

Or, if the double factorial is too weird:

$$\frac{9! - 2^{15}}{10000000_2}-\sqrt[5]{243}^2 = 50$$

Answer (score 4):

## The Complex Answers

I'd suggest $4.471527458208!=50$, but this isn't readily solvable. You suggested summations, and I thought "Hey! Why not *nested* summations?" The product of my "why not" statement: 
$$\sum _{n=0}^4\sum _{i=n}^7n=50$$

If you're okay with floor functions: 
$$\left\lfloor\prod _{n=1}^5\frac{\pi +e}{7}n\right\rfloor=50$$

A slightly more complicated one:
$$-1\left(\sum _{n=-3}^{11}-n\right)-10=50$$

If you want to complicate that (for a bit of fun), try, using Euler's identity for $-1$ and $n-2n$ for $-n$:
$$e^{i\pi}\left(\sum _{n=3e^{i\pi}}^{11}n-2n\right)-10=50$$

## The Somewhat Easy Answers

Using only 5's and 0's:
$$5.5\frac{505}{5}-5.55=50$$
Something kind of neat, using a pattern 1...7,1:
$$1\cdot 2+3\cdot 4+5\cdot 6+7-1=50$$
Where $x_n$ denotes $x$ in radix $n$:
$$302_4=50$$
$$200_5=50$$
$$32_{16}=50$$
$$62_8=50$$

## Set Theory

If $\alpha=\#A$ states that $\alpha$ is the cardinal of $A$, then:
$$\#\{x\in\mathbb{N}:5<x\leq55\}=50$$

Answer (score 4):

**Prime factorisation**

Simple and elegant: $50=2\times5^2$

Answer (score 3):

Compute the smallest positive integer $n$ such that the first two digits of $n^2$ is $\frac{n}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

How about this

$$50=12+18+20$$

[Reference on this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number)

Now, this would have your teacher scratch his head a little bit initially, but worth a shot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions:
$$\dfrac{50(-1)^{-i}}{i^{i^{2}}}=50$$
$$50=\sum_{n=1}^{10}(2n-1) \mod 10$$
$$50=1212_3$$
$$\left(4+\frac{4}{4}\right)\dfrac{\binom{4}{4-\frac{4}{4}}}{0.4}=50$$

Answer (score 1):

You could go Roman with $$\Huge{L}$$

Or with $$\begin{array}{c} \\ \\ \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc} \Huge{X}&&&&&&&&&&&&\Huge{X}\\ \\ \\ \\
&&&&&&\Huge{X}\\ \\ \\ \\ \Huge{X}&&&&&&&&&&&&\Huge{X} \end{array}\\ $$

Answer (score -1):

$$50 = \int_{\ln 1}^{3!+2^2}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})^4}{6\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}}\sqrt{3^2+4^2}dx$$

can make it more complicated but it wont fit on a cake :)

Comment: Well, but the integrand is constant in $x$ (it's just $5$), so it's not very interesting.

Comment: Where are you going to get the candles?